# google analytics event triggered but no data show in e-commerce using gtag.js

Tags: jquery, laravel, google-analytics, gtag.js

I am trying to implement gtag.js in my website to track enhance e-commerce data in google analytics. All event is firing in the realtime section of google analytics but no data showing in e-commerce section. Please help me.

```
<script>
                                var quantity = "<?php echo $value->product_quantity; ?>";
                                items.push({
                                    "id":"<?php echo $value->product_code; ?>",
                                    "name":"<?php echo $value->name; ?>",
                                    "list_name":"Cart List",
                                    "quantity":parseInt(quantity),
                                    "price":parseFloat("<?php echo $value->net_amount; ?>"),
                                    "list_position":parseInt("<?php echo $key + 1; ?>")
                                });
                            </script>
  <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                gtag('event', 'purchase', {
                                    "transaction_id": "<?=$trans_id?>",
                                    "value": parseFloat("<?=$net_amount;?>"),
                                    "currency": "RS",
                                    "tax": parseFloat("<?=$tax;?>"),
                                    "shipping": 0,
                                    "items": items
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
```

This is my success page code. All values are dynamic.

```
items.push({
                                    "id":product_code[1],
                                    "name":product_name,
                                    "list_name":"Search Results",
                                    "category": category,
                                    "variant": sub_category,
                                    "list_position":1,
                                    "quantity":1,
                                    "price":product_price
                                });
                                console.log(items);
                                gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
                                    "items": items
                                });
```

This is my add-to-cart code.